# Get age range for Facebook users who have not installed my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get an age range for Facebook users who have not installed my app?

The intended use is for an invite screen - we'd like to only show the user their friends who are 18 or older, but I can't figure out if this is possible. Would love any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**Insights API**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) of Facebook.

You can get the active users age with `application_active_users_age`

Comment: Shadowfax, I want an age range for users who have NOT installed my app. So I don't think that will work, correct?

Comment: Yes there isn't an API for the same, but I think from this you can get the age range of ppl who have not installed the app, right?

Comment: I don't think so. The way I read "Insights API", that gives me aggregate numbers for users of my app. What I want is a way to know an age range for a specific Facebook user who has not installed my app. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: that seems to be impossible to get